# Get first id of the latest 25000 entries?

Tags: mysql, order-by

I have a database with 200000 rows. Of those 200000 rows I want the latest 25000 and from those I need the oldest id (column entity_id).

This is my query so far: `select * from sales_flat_order order by entity_id desc limit 25000;`

This is aleady running forever. Is there a better way? Maybe its easier to get the entity_id on position 25000, but it has to be ordered, I need to have id on position 25000 of the latest entries.

This is the create statement of the table: https://pastebin.com/mrY7CTP8

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my post with a link to the create statement.

Comment: Do you want multiple rows for a particular `entity_id`?  Or do I not understand the question.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what column controls "latest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LIMIT offset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

```
select * 
from sales_flat_order 
order by entity_id desc limit 24999,1;
```

The OFFSET value allows us to specify which row to start from retrieving data.

offset    --- > 24999 hence the starting position is 25000.

row_count --- > 1 only one value returned

[Learn more on  MySQL LIMIT clause](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)